# Javascript function return wait for user action

Tags: javascript, function, action, wait

```
function dostuff() {
 $("#element").append("<div id='e1'>approve</div>");
 $("#element").append("<div id='e2'>deny</div>");
 $("#element #e1").click(function() {
  return "e1";
 });
 $("#element #e2").click(function() {
  return "e2";
 });
}

alert(dostuff());
```

I'd like to make a function that wait's with returning something until the user has done an action. like above. I'd like the function to return e1 if the user clicked on the e1 element.

Is this possible?
If not, what is the proper alternative manner to get this done?

Comment: Either promises or callback, you choose :)

Comment: So do you need to create on click event?

Comment: Uhm, not familiar with all the terms soi can only say.. i guess?

Comment: Okay, for example take the confirm function. once called the one and only confirm function, there will be a 'answer' from the function after a user action..